# Is it correct to call a mapping $\mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^n$ a "function"? And how to fix this definition?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, definition, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

The following is from the Mathematical Appendix of *Gravitation and Inertia* by Ignazio Ciufolini and John Archibald Wheeler.  The dangling open parenthesis is in the original.

> Given two $\left(\mathscr{C}^{r}\right)$ differentiable manifolds
> $\mathcal{M}^{m}$ and $\mathcal{N}^{n},$ a $\left(\mathscr{C}^{r}\right)$
> **differentiable mapping**, $f,$ from $\mathcal{M}^{m}$ into $\mathcal{N}^{n}$
> is a mapping such that at each point $\mathcal{P}$ of $\mathcal{M}^{m}$
> the function: $\psi\left(f\left(\phi^{-1}\left(x^{i}\dots x^{m}\right)\right)\right)$
> from $\mathbb{R}^{m}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a $\left(\mathscr{C}^{r}\right)$
> differentiable function (where $\phi$ is a homeomorphism between
> an open neighborhood of $\mathcal{P}$ in $\mathcal{M}^{m}$ and an
> open set of $\mathbb{R}^{m},$ and $\psi$ is a homeomorphism between
> an open neighborhood of $f\left(\mathcal{P}\right)$ in $\mathcal{N}^{n}$
> and an open set of $\mathbb{R}^{n}.$

In their definition of a tangent vector, it's pretty clear (to me) the term *function* means a single valued mapping $\mathcal{M}^m\to\mathbb{R}.$  Which I call a scalar field.

> A **tangent vector** at a point $\mathcal{P}$ is a mapping $\mathfrak{v}_{\mathcal{P}}$
> that to each differentiable function defined in the neighborhood of
> $\mathcal{P}$ assigns one real number, and which is linear and satisfies
> the Leibniz rule. That is
> \begin{align*}
> \mathfrak{v}_{\mathcal{P}}\left(\mathrm{a}f+\mathrm{b}g\right)= & \mathrm{a}\mathfrak{v}_{\mathcal{P}}\left(f\right)+\mathrm{b}\mathfrak{v}_{\mathcal{P}}\left(g\right)\text{, linearity; and}\\
> \mathfrak{v}_{\mathcal{P}}\left(f\cdot g\right)= & \mathfrak{v}_{\mathcal{P}}\left(f\right)g\left(\mathcal{P}\right)+f\left(\mathcal{P}\right)\mathfrak{v}_{\mathcal{P}}\left(g\right)\text{, Leibniz rule;}
> \end{align*}
> where $\mathrm{a},\mathrm{b}$ are real numbers and $f,g$ are differentiable
> functions.

In the book *Gravitation,* also co-authored by Wheeler, *function* means *scalar field*.  There are physics and applied mathematics books which speak of *vector valued functions* or *multi-valued functions*.  But (in my experience) in the rarefied air of pure mathematics, *function* on a manifold typically means *scalar field*.

Should the term *function* be replaced by *mapping* in the definition of *differentiable mapping* quoted above?

Also, should the missing closing parenthesis appear at the end of the quoted paragraph?

Comment: There is no consistency in the literature regarding this. For instance, topologists use "map" ("mapping") when continuity is assumed. As long as the authors are clear on their definitions, it will be all fine.

Comment: I think you're being overly pedantic.  You know what is meant, so just move on and don't worry about this stuff.  As for the usage of the term "function" in contexts that are not scalar-valued, it is standard to refer to the expression of one local coordinate system in terms of another around a point on a manifold as a *transition function*.  It is very rare to refer to it as a *transition mapping*.  Try googling each of those terms together with the term "manifold" and you'll see which is (much) more commonly used.

Comment: A more serious error in the definition of a $C^r$-mapping is that $\psi \circ f \circ \phi^{-1}$ is actually not a mapping "from $\mathbb R^m$ into $\mathbb R^n$" since the values of $\phi$ fill up an open set in $\mathbb R^m$ rather than all of $\mathbb R^m$: a mathematician wouldn't say a function maps $X$ to $Y$ if its domain is only part of $X$, but I can easily see a physicist doing that.

Comment: In the very rarefied air of pure mathematics, a function has a domain and codomain that can each be any nonempty set. So the codomain of this function can just be $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: A function without any modifiers in the context of manifolds usually means a real-valued function. There is no conflict with physicists speaking of vector-valued functions, since in attaching modifiers to "function" they are acknowledging the convention that the unmodified word "function" typically means a real-valued function.

Comment: @CharlesHudgins When I originally posted, I had not sorted out the placement of the missing ')'.  So it wasn't clear to me where the function under discussion lived.   I am again not sure if a "function on a manifold" allows for vector values.  The book's function  $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ has both arguments and values in $\mathbb{R}^n,$ and not on the manifold.  So the question of whether a function on a manifold allows for vector values isn't addressed.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton I think the answer is just "it can, but usually we just mean a real valued function."

Comment: @CharlesHudgins upon further reflection: there may be good reason to restrict function on a manifold to a scalar values.  Tenors are multilinear operator fields that mate with their contragediant counterparts to produce scalars.  But that's not fully satisfying since tenors  are priority objects; independent of coordinatization.  We can meaningfully speak of the curvature at a manifolds point without considering coordinates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it correct to call a mapping $\Bbb{R}^m\to\Bbb{R}^n$ a "function"?

Yes, it is correct. Is it standard/common? It depends on where you're using the term. The most general use of 'function' is as a 'rule' with a certain domain and codomain blablbla. It is also fairly common to use 'function' and 'mapping' synonymously in several areas. However, we may on occasion like to use certain terms in certain situations to give certain connotations.

For example, in differential geometry/Physics, it is not uncommon to reserve the term 'function' for when the target space is $\Bbb{R}$ and the domain is some manifold. At the same time, no one will/should fault you for using 'function' to mean things with other target spaces if you're consistently careful in specifically mentioning 'real-valued function' when that is what is intended.

If you open up a book on functional analysis, they're usually dealing with Frechet/Banach spaces, and continuous linear functions between them. Many authors will, for the sake of almost everyone's sanity, not keep repeating that they're talking about **continuous, linear functions**, and they might simply speak of 'operators'. If they ever intend anything to the contrary, it is expressly stated. Another example: in Hatcher's algebraic topology text, all maps are assumed to be continuous. Also, in many differential geometry texts, the term *manifold* almost always means $C^{\infty}$-manifold, and authors often make this convention explicitly known early on in the text.

Using extra adjectives is not a bad thing either if you suspect there is a possibility for confusion. For example, if you want to speak of a tensor field $F$ on a manifold, rarely would anyone refer to this by the term 'function' alone, nor by 'mapping' alone. Math is about communicating ideas, and the level of clarity 'required' is of course a subjective matter, and context is a huge part of math (as in any other form of writing... or life even). We write texts for humans, not robots.

---

Now regarding the passage you quote, I see no real ambiguity especially since they speak of *a function from ___ into ___*. You can't get any clearer than that (aside from mentioning that the domain is a certain *sub*set of $\Bbb{R}^m$, since that's usually the case with coordinate charts).

Also, regarding closing parenthesis, all I'll say is that no human is perfect.

Comment: I distinguish a function from a mapping by the requirement that the function be single valued.  That is, for example, $f\left(x\right)=x^2$ is a function.  But its inverse maps to two real numbers, so $f^{-1}$ is not a function.  But it is a mapping.  This may be why mappings $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ are often not called functions.  There is a rule that a function is single-valued.  But, if we call an element of $\mathbb{R}^m$ a *single value* then it becomes meaningful to extend the definition of *function* to multi-valued mappings.  Consistency and clarity are nice when splitting hairs.

Comment: @StevenThomasHatton In that case, "mapping" isn't the right word; *map*, *mapping*, *function*, *transformation* and perhaps many other terms are often used synonymously in many places. What you're distinguishing is a *function* vs a *relation*; a function being a special type of relation.

Comment: You are correct.  According to my notes a relation is a set of ordered pairs, and a mapping is a relation for which no two of the pairs have the same first element.

Comment: According to https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/fundamentals-mathematics-volume-1 the distinction twixt "mapping" and "function" is that a function is necessarily onto, whereas a mapping can be into.